# how to install memcache on macbook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the latest way to install memcache on snow leapord.

I found some tutorials on google but they are old, curious of the latest way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My favorite method for installing those kinds of products on OSX is: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Once that is setup, its just: `brew install memcached`

Comment: The recommended way to install homebrew is in your home directory, so no conflicts will arrise, and is easy to remove if you decide to use something else.

Comment: Update to my previous comment: The default install of homebrew is now in `/usr/local` not the user's home directory. So technically conflicts are possible but in practice I have not encountered any.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option is to use macports: http://www.macports.org/

I've never used homebrew but I hear it is quite a bit easier to set up and faster to use than macports.